# Foreach vs. for loop in getting children (their scripts)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just encountered something weird in Unity/c#. For some reason, the following foreach loop

```cs
foreach (Fade_in fade in animRotate.GetComponentsInChildren<Fade_in>())
{
    fade.delayInSeconds = 1f;
}
```

doesn´t work. However if I try to achieve the same thing with a for loop instead

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < animRotate.transform.childCount; i++)
{
    animRotate.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Fade_in>().delayInSeconds = 1f;
}
```

it does work. Could someone please explain to me why? 
The foreach loop didn´t show an error or something, it just didn´t change the float value.

Comment: maybe because `GetComponentsInChildren` doesn´t return the same objects as `animRotate.transform.GetChild(i)`? How did you examine "it just didn´t change the float value."? Did you put a breakpoint into the loop and checked what `delayseconds` is after assigning?

Comment: as @HimBromBeere says, that's probably cause you have more than one level of childrens in the hierarchy, and GetComponentsInChildren returns ALL the childrens I think. The For only returns the first level of hierarchy-childrens. Could you debug the count of the childrens returned please? ^^

Comment: It only has 2 Children with no ... "follow up children". And I can check the delaySeconds field in Unity during runtime, so I could see, that the foreach loop didnt change it but the for loop did.
I will debug the count tomorrow, I´m sorry but my worktime just ended. Thank you both for your comments so far!

Answer (score 0):

The `GetComponentsInChildren` function returns all components of `Type` type **in** the `GameObject` or any of its children.

You have 2 ways to get all the components without tha GameObject:

1. Use the `GetComponentsInChildren` with `includeInactive = false`:

```
foreach (Fade_in fade in animRotate.GetComponentsInChildren<Fade_in>(false))
{
    fade.delayInSeconds = 1f;
}
```

2. Use the `cast` function (`transform.Cast<Transform>().ToArray()`):

```
foreach (Fade_in fade in animRotate.transform.Cast<Fade_in>().ToArray())
{
    fade.delayInSeconds = 1f;
}
```

Comment: That was my mistake! I don´t know why (because I already know this), but I forgot to set includeInactive to true. Since they were disabled by the time I´m calling the script, they couldnt´ve been modified.